# Getting data from first table by using the data from second table

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, I could not find appopriate name for the question, if anyone can find a better name, I would be grateful if they edit. I am new at SQL, and I have the following question: I have two tables as stated below

Member -> Name, UID (PK), SupervisorUID.
WorkPlace -> WP_UID (PK), Name, SupervisorUID.

I need to create a query that returns Name of the member as well as their supervisors name that work in WorkPlace 'X'.

I am trying to use inner join but I am not able to achieve what i am trying to. The main question is, how can I select by WorkPlace name, and obtain both members name and supervisor's name.

Supervisor is also a member, so, WorkPlace.SupervisorUID should match with Member.UID

```
SELECT Member.Name, Y
INNER JOIN WorkPlace on WorkPlace.SupervisorUID = Member.UID
WHERE WorkPlace.Name = 'France'
```

I need to find what to put on Y.

I need to find how can I get supervisors name from taking uid from workplace, then going member table, find uid that matches with that supervisor uid and get the name.

```
Member
Jeremy 123 421
Jack 421 421
```

```
WorkPlace
1 France 421
```

I want to return the following table,

```
Jeremy Jack
```

Comment: You need to actually reference the member table in your query and join the 2 tables on the SupervisorUID columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have `WP_UID` as a column in `Member`. I am not sure if the `mysql` syntax is the same but if you add `WP_UID` to `Member`, the following works with MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT M1.Name, M2.Name
  FROM Member AS M1
  INNER JOIN WorkPlace AS WP on WP.WP_UID = M1.WP_UID
  INNER JOIN Member AS M2 on M2.UID = M1.SupervisorUID
  WHERE WP.Name = 'France' AND M1.UID <> M1.SupervisorUID
```

I added `M1.UID<>M1.SupervisorUID` so that supervisors are not displayed.

You could also remove `SupervisorUID` from `Member` and use this:

```
SELECT M1.Name, M2.Name
  FROM Member AS M1
  INNER JOIN WorkPlace AS WP on WP.WP_UID = M1.WP_UID
  INNER JOIN Member AS M2 on M2.UID = WP.SupervisorUID
  WHERE WP.Name = 'France' AND M1.UID <> WP.SupervisorUID
```